# Get list of icons from css file to use inside Angular 6 component

Tags: angular, css, icons

I'm in an Angular 6 application. I often have to create dropdowns that allow choosing custom icons from a specific file custom-icons.css.

For example:
TS:

```
@Component({
    selector: "my-component",
    templateUrl: "./my-component.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./my-component.component.scss"],
})
export class IconDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    icons = [
        "icon-up",
        "icon-down",
        "icon-left",
        //and 100 more icons
]
constructor() {}
ngOnInit() {}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="icon-container" *ngFor="let li of icons">
        <div>
            <i [ngClass]="[li]"> //this is to show icon
                <span class="icon-text"> {{ li }} </span> //this is to show the label for the icon
            </i>
        </div>
</div>
```

Now, I think that it is not a best practice to re-write every time all the icons in every component, where I have this kind of dropdown. 
For example, if the icons in custom-icons.css change, the lists in the components will not be automatically updated.

I'm not sure what to do. Maybe a script to run somehow that pick all classes from the file css could be a solution, but then I don't know how to use it inside an Angular Component.

Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

my friend, you need to use a service.
https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt4

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. A service can sure help me, but then what I don't know is how to access the css file to get all classes inside that service.